# Issue with Spark Java API, Kerberos, and Hive

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, kerberos

I'm trying to run a spark sql test against a hive table using the Spark Java API. The problem I am having is with kerberos. Whenever I attempt to run the program I get this error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:638)
    at tester.SparkSample.lambda$0(SparkSample.java:62)
    ... 5 more
```

on this line of code:

```
    ss.sql("select count(*) from entps_pma.baraccount").show();
```

Now when I run the code, I log into kerberos just fine and get this message:

```
18/05/01 11:21:03 INFO security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user <kerberos user> using keytab file /root/hdfs.keytab
```

I even connect to the Hive Metastore:

```
18/05/01 11:21:06 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://<hiveserver>:9083
18/05/01 11:21:06 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
```

But right after that I get the error. Appreciate any direction here. Here is my code:

```
public static void runSample(String fullPrincipal) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "true");
    System.setProperty("hive.security.authorization.enabled", "true");
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", fullPrincipal);
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", "true");
    System.setProperty("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

    Configuration conf = setSecurity(fullPrincipal);

    loginUser = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
    loginUser.doAs((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse");
        sparkConf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://<hive server>:9083");
        sparkConf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        sparkConf.set("hadoop.rpc.protection", "privacy");
        sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath",
                "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/*.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/conf:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/*.jar");
        sparkConf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath",
                "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/*.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/conf:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/*.jar");
        sparkConf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false");

        SparkSession ss = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .enableHiveSupport()
              .config(sparkConf)
              .appName("Jim Test Spark App")
              .getOrCreate();

        ss.sparkContext()
            .hadoopConfiguration()
            .addResource(conf);

        ss.sql("select count(*) from entps_pma.baraccount").show();
        return null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running Spark on YARN. You need to specify spark.yarn.principal and spark.yarn.keytab parameters. Please check running [Spark on YARN documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)